# Setting fieldset's "legend" to invsible

Tags: c#, asp.net, legend, fieldset

Is there another option for the  that I can use in C#? I have a condition that needs to be met in order to display one of these Legends. As of now, I don't see how I can set this legend to invisible from the .cs side...unless there is also some .asp equivalent???
Any suggestions?
Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `runat="server"` attribute on it and provide it an id:

```
<fieldset>
    <legend runat="server" id="leg">Some Legend</legend>
    Some value
</fieldset>
```

and then in the code behind use the id to hide it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    leg.Visible = false;
}
```